# How to use CASE statement to update data (as fractions) in the table?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Query Table:

| Different Fruits | Total Fruits | Fruits Fraction |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 5 |  |
| 2 | 6 |  |
| 2 | 2 |  |
| 4 | 6 |  |
| 1 | 1 |  |
| 6 | 6 |  |
| 6 | 16 |  |
| 4 | 20 |  |

Updated Table:

| Different Fruits | Total Fruits | Fruits Fraction |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 5 | 3/5 |
| 2 | 6 | 2/6 |
| 2 | 2 | 2/2 |
| 4 | 6 | 4/6 |
| 1 | 1 | 1/1 |
| 6 | 6 | 6/6 |
| 6 | 16 | 6/6 |
| 4 | 20 | 4/6 |

There is a total of 6 different fruits. However, the total fruits per record can be greater than 6.

I want to use a case statement such that:

```
WHEN Total Fruits < 6 THEN Fruits Fraction = Different Fruits/Total Fruits
ELSE Fruits Fraction = Different Fruits/6
```

I do not want to simplify the fraction, probably I think it would use character datatype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
SELECT "different fruits", "total fruits", 
  CASE 
    WHEN "total fruits" > 6 THEN "different fruits"||'/'||'6'
    ELSE "different fruits"||'/'||"total fruits"
    END AS fruits_fraction
FROM your_table
```

*db<>fiddle* link [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=f908b3d15c7a9741fb0d0a9286994475)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a `CASE` expression.
You can do it with [`MIN()` scalar function](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#min_scalar):

```
SELECT DifferentFruits, TotalFruits,
       DifferentFruits || '/' || MIN(TotalFruits, 6) FruitsFraction
FROM tablename;
```

Or, if you want to update the table:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET FruitsFraction = DifferentFruits || '/' || MIN(TotalFruits, 6);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=46a870ed38a6c4cdea22cf778081bf25).